# Tableau server installation: Missing multiple .jar files error

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am getting multiple .jar file missing errors while starting the tsm server. Adding some messages below (also complete log attached).

Tableau Server 2020.2.8 on CentOS 7.9.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.1110.1614/authorization-interfaces-3.19.0-jre8.rel.jar (No such file or directory)
...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.1110.1614/tab-service-discovery-interfaces-2.17.0-jre8.rel.jar (No such file or directory)
...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.1110.1614/tab-service-discovery-registry-1.47.0-jre8.rel.jar (No such file or directory)
...
'/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.1110.1614/tab-smtp-2.1.2-jre8.rel.jar' to determine if it contains static resources
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.1110.1614/tab-smtp-2.1.2-jre8.rel.jar (No such file or directory)

So on.. 64 missing jar files. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar problem.
I have a 4 node cluster running on centos 7.9.
Three nodes are working without issue. One node says it cannot find these three files:

tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.0913.2109/instrumentation-java-lib-1.9.33-jre8.rel.jar

tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.0913.2109/grpc-helpers-java-11.21.0-jre8.rel.jar

tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.0913.2109/global-settings-service-protobuf-0.4.0-jre8.rel.jar

The files exist with slightly different file names:

This is how they are actually named:

tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.0913.2109/instrumentation-java-lib-1.9.33.jar

tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.0913.2109/grpc-helpers-java-11.21.0.jar

tableau_server/packages/lib.20202.20.0913.2109/global-settings-service-protobuf-0.4.0.jar

so, the application is appending "-jre8.rel" to the end of the file name.

The other 3 cluster members have the same files as the one that is throwing this error.

I was thinking about throwing some sym links in there, but was hoping someone had a less "hack-ish" fix.